# Blockchain Application Architecture

Tags: blockchain

I need to develop an enterprise grade permissioned based blockchain application using Hyperledger fabric. To start with, I would like to understand how I should determine number of nodes required. Basically every organization will have one peer node that will process all the transactions. Apart from this reason, do we need nodes for anything else and how many of them? From architecture perspective, what aspects I need to consider?

Answer (score 0):

Each node can have some of this functions (router is a must):

1. router
2. full blockchain
3. wallet
4. miner

Since you're speaking about "one node per organization", you probably mean one "full" node per organization, meaning each organization will have a miner node, containing full blockchain locally.

The problem here is this: how can you guarantee each organization in your architecture will have the same mining power?..

Comment: Thanks for your response. My Application is permissioned Network. So there is no PoW or PoS consensus required. thinking of using BFT based consensus models.

Comment: If no PoW consensus is involved - why are you interested in Blockchain based solution in the first place?..

Comment: There are various consensus algorithms other than PoW. PoW is the standard consensus for Public Blockchain network. Whereas, my application is for enterprise where only trusted nodes participate. Hence, PoS is not required. By the way there are other reasons why blockchain is chosen.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the other reasons why blockchain is chosen in your case?
I haven't seen any truly WORKING blockchain solution which is not PoW based, and/or based on private blockchain.